# storing a numpy arrays in a list

Tags: list, numpy, indexing

I'd like to automate the process of loading some ASCII datafiles in numpy in order to plot them. The filenames are given to the program via terminal and the content is loaded and saved in a list. So basically the idea is to have list that contains numpy arrays that I can call later via indexing to plot each individual data.
The problem I have is that indexing is not working with these lists I make

```py
    subplots_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
    subplots_axes = [0,0,0,0] #this array will allow to create subplots for ''' 
                              # each of the above data
    fig = plt.figure()
    counter = 0
    for x in arguments_list:
        for filename in glob.glob(x):  
            mydata = np.loadtxt(filename)
            subplots_array[counter] = mydata # This loads the data from files 
            #specified in arguments argv into a subplot array as numpy sub-array
            counter += 1

    counter = 0    

    for x in subplots_array: 
         subplots_axes[counter] = fig.add_subplot(counter+1, 1, 1) 
         subplots_axes[counter].scatter(subplots_array[counter][:, 0]), subplots_array[counter][:, 1], s = 12, marker = "x")
         counter = counter + 1
```

This is the error I get. The funny thing is if I substitute "counter" with a numerical index like 0 or 1 or 2 etc, the data is plotted correctly, despite counter being defined as an index as well. So I am out of ideas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FirstTrial.py", line 89, in <module>
    subplots_axes[counter].scatter(subplots_array[counter][:,0], subplots_array[counter][:, 1], s = 12, marker = "x")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I hope this is enough description to help me solve the issue.

Comment: You say if you substitute counter for a number it works, can you post the example code for that?

Comment: That `for x in ...` loop looks funny.  You don't use `x` at all.  The `[:,0]` indexing actually passes a tuple, `(slilce(NOne),0)`.  That's ok if the recipient is an array, but not if its as list.

Comment: only line that change
    subplots_axes[counter].scatter(subplots_array[0][:, 0]), subplots_array[0][:, 1], s = 12, marker = "x")

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off, and with out your files I can't reproduce your code.  But here's what I think is happening:

```
In [1]: subplots_array = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]                                                     
In [2]: subplots_array[0]=np.ones((2,3))   # one or more counter loops
```

indexing with `counter==0` works:

```
In [4]: subplots_array[0][:,0]                                                                         
Out[4]: array([1., 1.])
```

but your error with the next counter value:

```
In [5]: subplots_array[1][:,0]                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0b654866bdee> in <module>
----> 1 subplots_array[1][:,0]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Here I replaced one element of `subplot_array` with a 2d array, but left the others alone.  They were initialed as lists:

```
In [6]: subplots_array                                                                                 
Out[6]: 
[array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]), [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

So the problem isn't with the `counter` type itself, but with the next level of indexing.